# BTC Stolen from Blockchain

Tags: fraud, theft

My bitcoin is stolen and following is how it happened?
A guy named, "David Robin" from Fremont,California US (obviously a fake one),  connected in a social network told me that I can mine for bitcoin when I connect my blockchain wallet to the blockchain mining network with the help of a antminer s9 hardware. 
He asked me to register a blockchain account and send him the wallet id and password so he can do the connections.
He also said that once he is done with the connections, I will change my password.
I shared with him my user name and password information. He did something with it. 
I changed my password and then topped up the Blockchain account with 0.198899 BTC, approx. $3,200/- on 27/12/17.
Within half an hour my wallet was empty.
I will appreciate if someone can explain how it has happened and if there is any way to get my BTC back?

Comment: You gave someone your username and YOUR PASSWORD (from blockchain.info?)... What do you want us to tell you? You obviously got scammed.

Comment: even if I changed my password?

Comment: The others explained it already. If the scammer has the private keys or the seed, he can do anything with your coins, irrelevant wheather you change any password.

Comment: Please put your stollen bitcoin address here to can see where this scammer put the money.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry you were scammed. One of the reasons that many experts don't think bitcoin is ready for mass adoption or retail use is precisely because people don't understand how to keep them secure.

You gave someone access to your key and they made a copy of it, then you locked out their access to your key. That didn't do any good though, because they had already made a copy.

Changing your password prevents anyone from using that password to access your wallet and keys. It doesn't prevent anyone who already knows your secrets from just creating another wallet with the same secrets.

About your only hope for getting the money back is tracking down the scammer.

Comment: Thanks for your response, any recommendation on how to track down this scammer?

Comment: There is no way to track him with the blockchain-transction-data. Maybe he used his real IP adress to communicate in the social network. That's the only possibility to track him.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, you were scammed.

If you sent him your wallet id and password, he could log in and copy your seed/private keys. So it wouldn't matter if you later changed your password, he could recreate your wallet on another device, and wouldn't need your password to access it on that device.

You'll have to contact the scammer to ask for your btc back, otherwise they're gone.

Comment: So my blockchain wallet is gone forever? I cannot use the same wallet anymore?

Comment: You would not want to use a wallet that someone else has the keys to. The site you used should have had a page (likely when you changed your password) explaining that changing a password doesn't lock out anyone who already has access but only prevents new people from gaining access.