# Bitcoin Mining as a Newbie (link wallet to another person's miner)

Tags: bitcoin-core, fraud

I'm new in bitcoin mining. I would wish to mining to make some profit. I have just talked to someone and he has told me I can partner with him to use his miner. I have some bitcoins ready with me and before I get started  I want to know how I will configure wallet to his miner.
What should I share with him and lastly how will I know that it is configured?
I'm trying to avoid being conned

Comment: What you have described is almost certainly a scam, the likes of which has been reported here many times before. Wallets DO NOT need to be 'configured for mining'; that is not how mining works at all. DO NOT share wallet id, login, private keys, mnemonic seed, etc with him. You will lose your bitcoins.

Answer (score 3):

> **What should I share with him**

Nothing, because

> **I'm trying to avoid being conned**

See for example

- [I think ive being scammed](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74413/13866)

  > I invested with a man who said he can mine me btc ... he then says I need to deposit another 950usd
- [How can I get a private key for this address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74362/13866)

  > I invested my bitcoins in someone's miner ...
  >    Now for the key he wants me to pay him $500
- [my money gone from wallet scam](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/73817/13866)

  > one trader miner told me that he would double the btc and do minning. i did the i gave access online to my wallet blockchain . later a big scam. my money disapper from wallet and a watch only adress linked created and the my entire btc transferred in to it
- [BTC Stolen from Blockchain](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/68697/13866)

  > A guy ... told me that I can mine for bitcoin ... Within half an hour my wallet was empty.
- [I've been asked to share wallet credentials to participate in mining. Is that a scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/66934/13866)

  > > I've been approached ... claiming that they would be able to increase my bitcoin by linking my wallet to their miner.