# i lost access to my bitcoin

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet, security, private-key

I did not have any idea about bitcoin but I wanted to get in, I met this guy who knew about it on facebook asked him if he could help. he sent me the link on blockchain to signup showed me how to buy coin from a merchant, I did as he said. everything was on going, later told me to give him my id and password so he can connect to a miner i asked y he said to make it possible to profit. so i did, which was my biggest mistake but i did not know then. my blockchain was growing close to $10000 trying to withdraw was the only problem. there was always a privatekey for to go ahead but i never got it. when ever i ask him he tills me to invest more to be able to withdraw. i woke up one day and all my profit was gone also when i gain profit it shows on my phone but doesn't appear on my portfolio i knew it was my id and password i gave this guy cause me damage. he doesn't reply my messages any more.

I know i cant get the coins back if any of u can help me redeem my account to show the profit i continue to get . all my profit was $27,830 but i never got a $ out of it.....some address are also on watch with profit close to $800 i just need support so i can support my mum. am out of collage cant get on rent even meal a day i will be grateful with any help.....somethings i feel like doing something to myself all depress everyday coz i have no one to talk to.....i just need a normal life .....will be grateful for help out...thank you.

please do not go no with this guy on facebook and anywhere for help name {DESCOMM OSAS he's a nigerian but says he live in California}, he's heartless

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bitcoin Mining as a Newbie (link wallet to another person's miner)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/74841/bitcoin-mining-as-a-newbie-link-wallet-to-another-persons-miner)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that you were scammed. Do not **ever** give someone your wallet identifier, password, private keys, seed phrase, etc!

> later told me to give him my id and password so he can connect to a miner i asked y he said to make it possible to profit

This is not how mining works at all. The scammer enticed you with 'profits', but in reality there were no mining profits. The scammer simply wanted you to think there was, in an effort to get more btc out of you.

What likely happened: When the scammer logged into your wallet, they made a copy of your wallet's seed phrase. With that phrase alone they can re-create your wallet on any other device, and they will have full access to your bitcoin. Your password protects the login to blockchain.info, but if you use the seed phrase to re-create the wallet on another device using different software, the password will not be required.

The second thing the attacker did was add a 'watch-only' bitcoin address to your wallet. Your wallet shows you the balance of that bitcoin address, but your wallet does not have the private key for that address, and thus cannot spend the bitcoin located there.

Once that is set up, the scammer will send some bitcoin to the watch-only address, and tell you it is 'mining profits'. This is a lie, while you thought you were generating profits, the real story is the scammer was just slowly adding bitcoin to that address, while telling you to deposit more btc to your wallet. Once you deposited more bitcoin, the attacker could use the seed phrase to recreate your wallet, and steal your bitcoin.

Sorry for your losses :(

At this point, abandon that wallet, do not ever use it to store bitcoin again. Create a new wallet, and be sure to guard it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

This bad experience teaches you not to give private key to anyone. From wallet we can buy or send only. There is no other minor or bloockchain related settings. Be alert from next time.