# Needing a Private Key in order to receive profits in Blockchain Wallet

Tags: transactions

I recently made an investment with Forexbitoptions and have made some profits. They have supposedly sent these profits to my Blockchain wallet but say it's not going through as I need a Private key for this. Question I have is do I need a private key for this and if so why would I have to pay for this private key in order to access my profits?

Comment: Sounds like you've been scammed. If you don't have the private key, the funds are not yours.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation of a fairly well-known scam. You never owned any bitcoins, there was never any profit, it is all fake. A watch-only address looks like there is money there, and profits accumulating but it's just a window onto someone elses money, not yours.

There are several similar stories on this website from other victims.

- [How to unlock private key of bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/77742/how-to-unlock-private-key-of-bitcoin/77744#77744)
- [How can I get a private key for this address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74362/13866)
- [Reg: Watch only Address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/75883/13866)
- [Bitcoin Mining as a Newbie (link wallet to another person's miner)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74841/13866)

The Forexbitoptions.com website gives their address as 586 Mcardle Road Kinsey, Alabama 36303, USA. If you put that address into Google maps and check streetview, it looks like some random small rural home (2000 sqft, 3 beds, single storey).

That address is also used by 247bitminer.com so I guess these scammers just copy each others websites.